# JsPrettier Sublime Error 'Couldn't Resolve Parser "babel"'

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm getting the following error when trying to JsPrettier my js and jsx code.

> Prettier reported the following error(s):
>
> [warn] Ignored unknown option `--html-whitespace-sensitivity=css`.
>   [error] Error: Couldn't resolve parser "babel"

I've reinstalled both plugins now and am still getting the same error. Currently working in a project with create-react-app.

JsPrettier version 1.24.0
Sublime version 3.1.1

These are my Babel settings:

```
  "debug": false,
  "use_local_babel": true,
  "node_modules": {
    "windows": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules",
    "linux": "/usr/lib/node_modules",
    "osx": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
  },
  "options": {}
}
```

Is there a way to point JsPrettier to Babel? I'm not sure how exactly Sublime, Babel and Prettier all interact with each other. I'm guessing its just a matter of telling JsPrettier where the babel parser is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have this same issue. I dont see a `node_modules` in that path listed in my babel settings though. Did you recently update npm? I'm wondering if the modules have moved

Comment: If I set the syntax of a file to plaintext then try autosave, prettier works correctly. Does it do the same for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: If you want to use the local install of prettier in your project, omit the `-g` from all commands*

First, update your global version of prettier:
`npm update -g prettier`

`npm list -g prettier` now gives me `prettier@1.16.2`

Now update your JsPrettier User settings (Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > JsPrettier > Settings - User) and set the `"prettier_cli_path"` to point at your global bin

```
// JsPrettier.sublime-settings
{
...
  "prettier_cli_path": "/Users/abby/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/prettier",
...
}
```

(Check what the correct path is by running `npm root -g` and update it to the prettier bin)

Comment: Thank you Abby! Worked perfectly! I switched to yarn and that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Similar error in a slightly different setting.

```
------------------
JsPrettier ERROR 
------------------

Prettier reported the following error(s):

[error] Error: Couldn't resolve parser "babel"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have the prettier package installed locally also in our project, as specified in the package.json file.

I found it's of a quite old version. So I updated it and then error is gone.

```
$ yarn remove prettier
$ yarn add prettier -D
```